# How to populate date and time in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, date, time

How can I use **dropdownlist** control for **date**. I have to build a list of dates starting with today and dates for next 60 days which exclude the booked dates. I have build a query that will check each day, if all time slots are booked, if the slots are booked than I don't have add that date to the list.

Now regarding time. The time is from **09:00 Am** to **10:00 Pm**. But I have to show from **09:00Am** to **09:30Pm**. When a date is selected, how can I populate the free time slots in a new **dropdownlist** control. I have services with duration required, so let the user select the available time from **dropdownlist**. On select I have add the selected time + duration required. If a service takes more time then available time for the day, I have to show a message asking user to select next available date.

```
TABLE [dbo].[Appointments] (
[Name]              NVARCHAR (100)   NOT NULL,
[ShopperId]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[Date]              DATE             NOT NULL,
[Time]              TIME (7)         NOT NULL,
[AppointmentNo]     INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[AppointmentStatus] NVARCHAR (100)   NOT NULL,
[Services]          NVARCHAR (1000)  NOT NULL)

TABLE [dbo].[AddService] (
[ServiceId]        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[ServiceName]      NVARCHAR (500)   NOT NULL,
[DurationRequired] SMALLINT         NOT NULL,
[Description]      NVARCHAR (2000)  NOT NULL,
[Active]           BIT              NOT NULL)
```

How to Build a list of type string. Pull all appointments from database from today's  date to next 60 days where day is not fully booked. So that I can get list of all dates that are available.

Than I need to count the number of items in the list. If the count is less than 60 then get the last date from the list and add dates from last date until the list becomes of size 60.

Then convert the datetime data type to string using .shortdatetime.tostring and bind it to the dropdown control.

Comment: There are different services and the time slot is based on the services. For Example, Hair Cut duration 30min, Shaving Duration 30 min. If user selects these two services than these duration will be added and than the time slot of 1 hr will be booked for that user. than that much time will not be displayed to another user. I have 5 staff members so a particular time will be available for 5 persons.

Comment: In services Salon Services like Hair Cut, Shaving, Facial, Face Massage is stored.

Comment: Any one got the solution??? @isthatso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this to add dates in one dropdownlist control and in second dropdownlist control I have added times.

```
DropDownListDate.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()); //for adding current date
    for (int i = 1; i <= 59; i++) //loop to add next 60 days
    {
        DropDownListDate.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString());
    }

    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("09:00"); //for adding start time
    for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) //Set up every 30 minute interval
    {
        ListItem li2 = new ListItem(dt.ToShortTimeString(), dt.ToShortTimeString());
        li2.Selected = false;
        DropDownListTime.Items.Add(li2);
        dt = dt.AddMinutes(30);
```